# Can static blocks and variables be used inside anonymous inner classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop, static, anonymous-class

Do static blocks and static variables work inside anonymous inner classes in java?

Hello, I was following a video explanation on YouTube and it was talking about the `static blocks` and the `static variables` and that you cannot use them inside the `anonymous inner classes`

**the code**

```
package Anonymous;

public class main {
    public static class TestClass {

        public void TestMethod() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test = new TestClass() {
            static int p = 5;
            final static int y = 5;

            static {

            }

            @Override
            public void TestMethod() {
                System.out.println("test 2");
            }
        };
        test.TestMethod();
    }
}
```

Now when I run on my computer (does not give an error)

[image]

But in the YouTube video or online compiler (it gives this error)

[image]

Now what is the reason for this difference?

And Do `static blocks` and `static variables` work inside `anonymous inner classes` or not?

Comment: Clearly it works, and you have no idea which version of Java was being used in the video.  Please consider this an object lesson in the appropriate level of trust to place in stuff you find on the Internet.  As Gorbachev once said, "Trust but verify".  There's a lot of garbage out there, and you should trust your compiler/IDE more than some random internet video.

Comment: Judging by questions on SO, YouTube tutorials are not the best way to learn Java.

Answer (score 6):

Up to java version 15, you can't do that. Starting with java 16, you can. Clearly on your computer you are running java 16 or higher, and the youtube thing is running 15 or lower.

Comment: This was added as part of [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).